# How many CR 1/4 does it take to challenge a level 3 party?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, encounter-design

I'm running my first campaign and I'm confused about the CR of monsters. I started out with five level 2 characters. I have a few encounters that work so far, but theres one I'm confused about. If the CR of a monster 1/4, and the characters are now level 3, with a lvl 1 NPC and a lvl 5 NPC. How many of these CR 1/4s will it take to be a challenge?

Comment: Have you looked at the encounter building guidelines in the DMG? (And the additional notes about it in Xanathar's?)

Answer (score 26):

<sup>*[This all assumes you're looking for a medium encounter, as defined in the DMG. Adjust upward or downward for easy, hard, or deadly, as instructed in the various sections.]*</sup>

### By the DMG

"Creating a Combat Encounter" (pp.81-84) has your instructions. For example, a "medium" encounter for a party of 5 level 3 PCs would have an adjusted XP budget of 750--1125.

A CR 1/4 creature is valued at 50XP (MM. p.9), so we can fiddle with numbers and encounter multipliers (DMG p.82) to see that 6 creatures would be too few, 9 would verge on "hard." **So your answer's 7 or 8, *possibly* 9.**

### By XGtE

"Encounter Building" (pp.88-91) has more guidelines. There we'd see that for level 3 characters I should provide CR1/4 enemies in a 2:1 ratio. **So XGtE recommends 10 of them.**

### By the sheep

I say throw **anywhere between six and ten at them, depending on what makes sense** in the fiction. Then **use your gameplay** and game-time decisions **to adjust difficulty** as it goes. If ten's too many have a few cowardly ones break off the first time one goes down. If six is too few, have them fight smart. (Placing the encounter in terrain/location that you can choose to use to your advantage--or *not*--is key to this, I believe. Personally I'm *not* a fan of bringing in reinforcements unless the party knows they're in a monster-ridden location like a hostile camp, but others report success with that tactic.)

The quick calculation I use is to try and make sure the monsters are dishing out damage about 1/2 the rate the party generally does.<sup>*</sup> Your L3 adventurers are probably dishing out about 10 or 12 dmg per round, hitting 2/3 of the time, for a party total of 35-40. How many CR 1/4 does it take to dish out 1/3 of that? Say they do 6 dmg per round at the same hit-rate, we're looking at 5 monsters. But it's nicer to have too many than to have too few--it's much easier to "dial back" as a GM--so that's where the recommendation of 6-10 comes in.

---

<sup>* - This is based on the notion of six encounters and two short rests per adventuring day; if a "medium" encounter starts its lifecycyle dishing out 1/2 the party's damage and decreases somewhat-linearly (as monsters start dropping) to 0, the time-averaged damage output sits around 1/4 the party's. But monsters don't always drop that quickly (though these little ones *will*), so the real time-average is a little higher, call it 1/3. Which is what I really want from a medium encounter so that two of them will make the party want for a short rest, and an "easy" should be easier than that and a "hard" has room to be noticeably harder.</sup>

Comment: I would also add that depending on the initiative, AC and luck, what started as 10 monsters could look more like 6 or 7, even before the monsters get to their turn; unless the party got surprised.

Comment: No idea where by the sheep comes from but I do like it :)

Comment: @SeriousBri it comes from the bit of [chat] starting [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30638910#30638910).

Comment: Why is the number so low? For a party of 1 (5th level), 5 (3rd level), 1 (1st level) I got 11 at the very least with an adjusted XP of 1375 with a minimum 1300 of XP for a medium encounter for a party with given composition.

Answer (score -2):

There is this site called "kobold fight club" which helps building encounters https://kobold.club/fight/#/encounter-builder

Comment: Hi, welcome to RPG Stack exchange. This answer could benefit from being expanded. Suggesting Kobold Fight Club as a resource could form part of a good answer. However, just directing the asker to Kobold Fight Club, with no further information, doesn't really answer the question, and is likely to attract down votes.